# Aspell 0.6 for Windows

Tags: windows, open-source, gnu, aspell

I am looking for the Win32 binary version of Aspell 0.6.

I am under the impression that the [LyX Project](http://lyx.org) maintained a Windows fork of Aspell (at least until v. 1.4), but I have not been able to find a version of it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://www.wxperl.co.uk/aspell/
As of today, version 0.60.6 in 32bit and 64bit variants.

Comment: moskito-x: Sadly so. I contacted the developer on Sep 17, and he responded that the aspell binaries (and backups) were lost in a recent transition of the wxperl.co.uk website.  Here's a quote that I don't think he'll mind I share: "I need to check that the local version of everything works ( that is, the patches + original source plus build scripts and instructions mean you can actually build the thing yourself ) so binary release will be delayed a short time until I can check that out."

Comment: Hopefully wxperl.co.uk will host their binary again, but in the meantime, there is a 0.60.3 windows binary available that has reportedly been used successfully: [Blog post](http://nosq.com/2005/07/aspell-0603-for-win32/) and [exe](http://www.nosq.com/download/aspell-0.60.3.exe)

Comment: Link in comment also no longer works. Anyone as a new link to a 0.60 binary?

Comment: Wayback machine to the rescue: https://web.archive.org/web/20160401000000*/http://www.nosq.com/download/aspell-0.60.3.exe

Comment: You can find a tutorial for the 0.60.3 in the wayback machine too: https://web.archive.org/web/20160421214934/http://nosq.com/2005/07/aspell-0603-for-win32/